# Conversion Error while using the FindFirstFile()

Tags: c

I am using the `FindFirstfFile()` in a method to read the files in a folder
In this method am reading the directory path as one of the function argument

```
Functionname(structname struct_var,char *path);
```

I considered the path.i.e eg:"D:\foldername".now do the below logic to read the file name with particular extension.

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData; 
HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; 
DWORD dwError; 
     char* Buffer;
     char Buffer1[256];
     char *schar;
 char *cd;
//wchar_t *cd;
FILE* name_text;
 char keyb;
 FILE *fp;
 i = 0;
time_t t_time;
int count=0;
sprintf(cd,"%s",Path);
printf("%s",cd);

  printf ("Target directory is %s.\n",cd); 

   strcpy(schar,cd);
       sprintf(Buffer,"%s",schar);
   strcat(Buffer,"\\");
   sprintf(Buffer1,"%s",Buffer);
   strcat(schar,"\\*.b11");

  hFind = FindFirstFile(cd, &FindFileData);//getting conversion error 

 if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)  
{ 
  printf ("Invalid file handle. Error is %u.\n", GetLastError()); 
  return (-1); 
}
```

> Error:1>f:\2-2-2012\myproject\myproject\module.cpp(94) : error C2664: 'FindFirstFileW' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char *' to 'LPCWSTR'

how to match the conversion data type for the variable "cd" with out error.

Any soultion to it?

Comment: While unrelated to your problem at hand, I see that you copy some text into `cd` (using `sprintf`) but you don't actually point `cd` to anywhere which means it can point to anywhere in memory and you might overwrite some crucial memory. Either point it to a buffer, or allocate memory (remember to free!) or use a normal char array.

Answer (score 3):

The source is being compiled for UNICODE. There are two available functions:

- FindFirstFileA (ANSI version)
- FindFirstFileW (Wide character version)

when building for UNICODE `FindFirstFile` is actually `FindFirstFileW`, otherwise `FindFirstFile` is `FindFirstFileA`.

The compiler is complaining that you are passing `char*` instead of a wide character buffer.

You need to do one of the following:

- to compile not for UNICODE
- explicity call `FindFirstFileA()`
- use a wide character buffer

Also, there are a few bugs in the code:

```
sprintf(cd,"%s",Path);
```

But `cd` is a `char*` and is never set to point to any allocated memory, similar problem for `schar` and `Buffer`. You need to determine the full length of the path that you need to construct, allocate memory and then construct the path (remember to `free()` the allocated buffer).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.when ever i set the character set property as "Not set" or "use Multi-byte character".getting 85 other errors.

I changed the FindFirstFile() to FindFirstFileA().still gets type conversion errors.
error C2664: 'FindFirstFileA' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'wchar_t *' to 'LPCSTR'.because changed the Cd variable data type as wchar_t

here path data type in argument is char.here If i change the char to wchar_t its affetcts other part of program.Is there any other way to do it.?

Comment: Keep `cd` as `char*` if you explicitly call `FindFirstFileA()`.